# Compare dates problems

Tags: oracle

I created a table with the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE INDICADOR_DADOS
(

  ID       VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)   NOT NULL,
  DATE_START       DATE        NOT NULL,
  DATA_END         DATE        NOT NULL,
)
```

Now wanted before adding, checks if there are dates between which intend to add the following query:

```
 select COUNT(*) as count from indicador_dados
        where id='23' and TO_DATE(data_inicio,'yyyy/mm/dd') 
            between to_date('2013/05/15','yyyy/mm/dd')
            and to_date('2013/05/16','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

The problem is that this query is not to be returned to 1, and because they must have in the database 05/03/2013 (date_start) and 17/05/2013(date_end). Someone can help me?

maybe duplicate: [oracle-datetime-in-where-clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749369/oracle-datetime-in-where-clause) but not it helped me to resolve

Comment: What dates are you actually looking for in the resultset though? Please edit your answer and explain in plan English. In the above example, do you want '2013/05/16 23:59:59' to be included, for example?

Comment: Already edited. I apologize for my poor english. I just want to compare dates and not time

Comment: Is this table for a reservation system (like for rooms in a hotel)?

Comment: Yes, more or less. It is to record how many calls were made ​​between certain date

Comment: Sample data and expected result would help. You may need to use this condition `WHERE id='23' AND date_start < DATE '2013-05-06' AND DATE '2013-05-15' < date_end`

Comment: @ypercube After all it is my stupidity. I was just comparing the date of the beginning and never ending Thanks

Comment: The above was supposed to be:  `WHERE id='23' AND date_start < DATE '2013-05-16' AND DATE '2013-05-15' < date_end`

Comment: I am still having difficulty. With the following query can not achieve the desired result and gave as an example: `select * from indicador_dados where to_date(data_start, 'yy/mm/dd') >= '2013/05/15' and to_date(data_end, 'yy/mm/dd') <= '2013/05/16'`

Comment: Why is an apparantly-numeric ID column defined as varchar2?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Because the id is text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two problems with your date filter:

1. You're applying `TO_DATE` on a `DATE` datatype. It is not only **superfluous**, but it actually causes **unexpected behaviour**.

   Here's how Oracle analyses the expression `TO_DATE(data_inicio,'yyyy/mm/dd')`:

   - Oracle searches for a function named `TO_DATE` that has two arguments (`DATE`, `VARCHAR2`)
   - Since no such function exists, Oracle looks for related functions that are accessible with implicit conversions.
   - (Un)fortunately, a single [`TO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm#i1003589) function exists, so there is no ambiguity here, the function choosen is `TO_DATE(VARCHAR2, VARCHAR2)`.
   - Your date is converted to a VARCHAR2 with the **current session date format**, which means that the behaviour is unpredictable. The expression is equivalent to:

     ```
     TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(data_inicio, 'current NLS_DATE_FORMAT'), 'yyyy/mm/dd')
     ```

     In this case you will lose the time component of the date if your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `YYYY/MM/DD`.

   You should never rely on implicit conversions because the behaviour is context dependent.
2. Your interval filter is wrong: two intervals `[A,B]` and `[C,D]` will intersect if and only if:

   - `A <= D`
   - and `B >= C`

Your query should look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT
  FROM indicador_dados
 WHERE id = '23'
   AND date_start  <= to_date('2013/05/16', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
   AND date_end >= to_date('2013/05/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Comment: Very thz for your help. You just solve my problem.